# Is state management through setState() in Flutter called Reactive State Management?

Tags: flutter, dart, observable, reactive-programming, flutter-getx

Using **obx** of **GetX** would be referred to as reactive state management, but does the same apply to **setState()** of Flutter?

With '**setState()**', we specifically have to pass the variable in this function to make its updated value known to all whereas by attaching .**obx** the variable's updated value gets known to everyone on its own.

Is state management through **setState**() in Flutter called Reactive State Management?

Answer (score 0):

Obx in Getx is called reactive programming because it uses streams under the hood or the RX variable in Getx is more close to [RxDart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) in short you can say that reactive programming is done with the help of streams and subscriptions we call it reactive because it automatically updates new values.

the getx also provides a statemangemt solution with GetBuilder and an update method in the Getx controller. Getbuilder is using a set state under the hood and is not a reactive solution in general

note: upvote and marked the answer if you find it helpful.

[image]

Comment: Please read the question again. I have asked about "setState()".

Comment: the simple answer of your questions is no the set state is not a reactive programming the reactive programming is done by using streams.

Comment: why do we called Getx .OBs a reactive state management? 

Because it's using streams under the hood.